# Query: Select and display next highest value as new column

Tags: mysql

I have this query which lists out IDs from "pages" on our site.

```
SELECT mdl_page.id
  FROM mdl_page, mdl_log, mdl_user
  WHERE mdl_log.module = "page"
    AND mdl_log.action = "view"
    AND mdl_user.id = mdl_log.userid
    AND mdl_log.info = mdl_page.id
    AND mdl_log.course = 178
```

The result is simple:

```
|  ID |
|-----|
|  3  |
|  4  |
|  7  |
|  11 |
```

Notice the jumps in the count. I'm trying to get something like this:

```
|  ID | NEXT ID |
|-----|---------|
|  3  |    4    |
|  4  |    7    |
|  7  |    11   |
|  11 |    12   |
```

Can anyone point in me in the right direction for this?

**UPDATE**

One twist, the system (not my own) I have to run the query through only allows queries that begin with 'SELECT'.

Comment: so the page ids for a course are selected. Is there an explanation for what you want to do with this next id column? If it is always ascending, then why not **order by mdl_page.id asc** to know the correct order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways i can think of use a co-related subquery,in your sub query compare the value from main query and sorts it in ascending manner and limit the result to one

```
SELECT 
          p.id ,
          (SELECT 
          p1.id 
        FROM mdl_page p1 
          JOIN mdl_log l1 ON (l1.info = p1.id) 
          JOIN mdl_user u1 ON (u1.id = l1.userid) 
        WHERE l1.module = "page" 
          AND l1.action = "view" 
          AND l1.course = 178
          AND p1.id > p.id 
        ORDER BY p1.id ASC LIMIT 1) NEXT_ID
    FROM mdl_page p 
    JOIN mdl_log l ON (l.info = p.id) 
    JOIN mdl_user u ON (u.id = l.userid) 
    WHERE l.module = "page"  AND l.action = "view"  AND l.course = 178
    ORDER BY p.id
```

and use a rank query, in rank query i am left joining the same query with the less than condition `ON (t.`id`< t1.id)` so it will result in multiple rows like (3,4),(3,7),(3,11) so i need to pick the first combination of 3,4 for this i have used a rank query to give the rank to the items that belong to same group, in parent where i am just restricting the result set to show the first pair for each group

```
SELECT t3.id,t3.NEXT_ID FROM (
    SELECT t.id id, t1.id NEXT_ID ,
    @r:= CASE WHEN @g = t.id THEN @r +1 ELSE 1 END rownum,
    @g:= t.id
     FROM
        (SELECT 
          p.id 
        FROM
          mdl_page p 
          JOIN mdl_log l ON (l.info = p.id) 
          JOIN mdl_user u ON (u.id = l.userid) 
        WHERE l.module = "page" 
          AND l.action = "view" 
          AND l.course = 178
        ORDER BY p.id  
        ) t
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT 
          p.id 
        FROM
          mdl_page p 
          JOIN mdl_log l ON (l.info = p.id) 
          JOIN mdl_user u ON (u.id = l.userid) 
        WHERE l.module = "page" 
          AND l.action = "view" 
          AND l.course = 178
        ORDER BY p.id ) t1 ON (t.`id` < t1.id)
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @g:=0,@r:=0) t2
    ORDER BY t.`ID` , t1.ID 
) t3
WHERE t3.rownum = 1
```

resutset you will get as null for 11 if there is no more record exist which have an id greater than 11 ,or in other words the last record will have a null in next_id column

```
ID  NEXT_ID
3   4
4   7
7   11
11  NULL
```

Comment: Excellent! I didn't expect all this. The first query prints exactly what I need. The second one isn't accepted, I think, because variables are not allowed in this system. I really appreciate your time on this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should create a temporary table, which is pretty much the same as the query you're running and erase the first line?

Then run your query and join it with the temporary table?

Comment: Thanks. See my update. Unfornately, I cannot begin with any other operation besides SELECT. Starting with CREATE or SET is not allowed.